# Website hyperlink in email sent with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have been searching for a way to add a hyperlink to an email sent through VBA. I found this code but am not sure how to implement it:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add [a1], "google.com", _
      , "Go to Google.", "Google"
```

This is what I have got so far, I would like to have the word 'here' go to google.com:

```
 Sub email_tracking()

        MailFromMacwithOutlook bodycontent:="Hi " & Range("C3").Value & "<br><br>" & "Thank you for placing an order with us, your order has now been packed and dispatched. " & _
        "Please click here to track you order. " & "<br>" & " Typically orders will take between 1-2 working days to arrive. " & "<br><br>" & _
        "Carrier: Royal Mail " & " <br>" & _
        "Tracking Number: " & Range("C4").Value & " <br><br>" & _
        "If you encounter any difficulties or have any questions please email us and we will get back to you within 24 hours. " & " <br><br>" & _
        "The Logistics Team", _
                    mailsubject:="Order Dispatched (" & Range("C2").Value & ")", _
                    toaddress:="EMAIL ADDRESS HERE", _
                    ccaddress:="", _
                    bccaddress:="", _
                    attachment:="", _
                    displaymail:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have outlook on your system?

Comment: Yes, it works fine, just want to add the hyper link :).

Comment: Lol, I read MailFromMacwithoutOutlook.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `<a href="www.google.com">here</a>`:

```
MailFromMacwithOutlook bodycontent:="Hi " & Range("C3").Value & "<br><br>" & "Thank you for placing an order with us, your order has now been packed and dispatched. " & _
        "Please click <a href=""www.google.com"">here</a> to track you order. " & "<br>" & " Typically orders will take between 1-2 working days to arrive. " & "<br><br>" & _
        "Carrier: Royal Mail " & " <br>" & _
        "Tracking Number: " & Range("C4").Value & " <br><br>" & _
        "If you encounter any difficulties or have any questions please email us and we will get back to you within 24 hours. " & " <br><br>" & _
        "The Logistics Team", _
                    mailsubject:="Order Dispatched (" & Range("C2").Value & ")", _
                    toaddress:="EMAIL ADDRESS HERE", _
                    ccaddress:="", _
                    bccaddress:="", _
                    attachment:="", _
                    displaymail:=False
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the double quotes (to have a quote (") inside a string).

Comment: Still nothing, do you have to add .htmlbody somewhere?

Comment: Does it open a mail window? Or does it give an error in VBA (and which)?
Other thing you might try is to put the content between `<body>` tags: `bodycontent:="<body>Hi ....</body>`.

Comment: If you are referencing an actual `olMailItem` then you can use the `.HTMLBody` .I'm not familiar with `bodycontent`

Comment: @Bas Verlaat: tbowden is using the send mail function for Mac: [MailFromMacwithOutlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh859489(v=office.14).aspx).